# Javascript named jump to anchor

Tags: javascript, anchor

I'm trying to make a function that refreshes the page (and resets the quiz) and jump to that anchor that has the button.

This works fine for chrome and firefox but in IE it just refreshes to the first named anchor.

My code:

```
function resetQuiz(showConfirm) 
{
  if(showConfirm)
    if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to reset your answers and start from the beginning?"))
      return false;
 window.location.reload(); //this works for chrome and firefox
 window.location.hash="mercquiz"; //tried this for IE. doesnt work

}
```

Comment: Try putting curly braces for the `if` blocks. I know in ANSI C that can be an ambiguous situation

Answer (score 2):

You may be reloading the page before the hash has a chance to update.

Try this instead:

```
var loc = window.location.toString();
window.location = loc.substring(0, loc.indexOf("#")) + "#mercquiz";
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: This doesnt seem to be working on any browsers. It just appends #mercquiz to the url (test.html#mercquiz#mercquiz) Just to clarify, my quiz is on test.html#mercquiz and the reset button is on that anchor division.

Comment: Strange... usually changing the `window.location` property will force a reload. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Waiwhetu ok, try it now. It updates the hash and THEN reloads the page.

Comment: Works in chrome/FF but not IE :(

Comment: That is really, really strange. I can't seem to find anyone else with this problem either... Hopefully an IE-knowledgable answerer will come our way.